# Aggregating Left Join in NHibernate using QueryOver/ICriteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have two simple classes

```cs
public class Blog
{
  public Blog(){
    Comments=new List<Comment>();
  }
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Title { get; set; }
  public virtual string Text { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and

```cs
public class Comment
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Author { get; set; }
  public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Mapped using AutoMap and all is great with the world. I can add and save entities no problems.

What I'd like to do is use QueryOver to get the number of comments per blog, but include those blogs where there are no comments, so in SQL:

```sql
SELECT b.Title,COUNT(c.ID) AS Comments
FROM Blogs b LEFT JOIN Comments c ON b.ID=c.BlogID
```

and get

```
Title  Comments
Blog 1 0
Blog 2 0
Blog 3 0
Blog 4 4
Blog 5 0
```

The closest I've got is

```cs
var results=session.QueryOver<Blog>()
.Left.JoinQueryOver<Comment>(b=>b.Comments)
.TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
.List<Blog>()
.Select(b => new {
Id = b.Id,
Title = b.Title,
Comments=b.Comments.Count
});
```

which gets the right answer, but the SQL runs as

```sql
SELECT b.Id,b.Title,c.ID,c.Author,etc... AS Comments
FROM Blogs b LEFT JOIN Comments c ON b.ID=c.BlogID
```

then does the counting at the client end, which doesn't seem the most efficient way of doing it.

Can this be done with QueryOver or ICriteria? I'd rather not use hql if possible.

The entire solution is available at https://github.com/oharab/NHibernateQueriesSpike if you want to see all the config etc.

Cheers

B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you always find the answer just after you've posted the question?

The answer was the JoinAlias  method, with an alias placeholder:

```
Comment comment=null;
var results=session.QueryOver<Blog>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(b=>b.Comments,()=>comment)
    .SelectList(
        list=>list
        .SelectGroup(b=>b.Id)
        .SelectGroup(b=>b.Title)
        .SelectCount(b=>comment.Id)
    )
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(b => new {
                Id = (Guid)b[0],
                Title = (string)b[1],
                Comments=(int)b[2]
               });
```

This does exactly as I expected it to.

B.